# Error [Column 'post_title' cannot be null] when title is disabled for Custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, errors, title

I am creating a custom post type for a front-end slider. It takes the value entered into a custom field and uses it as post-title. It works perfectly on my localhost and on my personal host. However, when I install it on my client's host, I am given the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: wys_slider_title in /data02/client_id/public_html/wp-content/themes/waiyin2015/inc/cpt/slides.php on line 302
WordPress database error: [Column 'post_title' cannot be null]
```

Line 302 refers to the function where the slide title is posted.  The full function is as follows:

```
function wys_slide_title( $data , $postarr ) {
    if( $data['post_type'] == 'slider' ) {
        $slide_title = $_POST['wys_slider_title']; // <<<<<< This is line 302
        $new_title = $slide_title;
        // Set slug date
        $post_date = date('Ymd-His');
        // $post_slug = sanitize_title_with_dashes($post_date, '', $context = 'save');
        $post_slugsan = sanitize_title($post_date);
        $data['post_title'] = $new_title;
        $data['post_name'] = $post_slugsan;  
    }
    return $data;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'wys_slide_title' , '99', 2 );
```

`wys_slider_title` is a field inside of a meta box, which contains the slide's caption, image, and a link field. Again, there are no errors when I use this on my localhost or my hosting provider, but my client's hosting provider is different and is throwing this error.
Due to this, I'm not able to post any content and I'm being told my content will be `"Submitted for review"`, even though I'm the administrator for the site.

Can anyone help with what might have gone wrong?

EDIT: It has been requested that I post the function where `wys_slider_title` is declared. This is the full script used to run the post type:

```
// Stories custom post type

add_action('init', 'wys_sliders');

function wys_sliders() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Front Slider', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Front Slider', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'post type item'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Slide'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Slide'),
        'new_item' => __('New Slide'),
        'view_item' => __('View Slide'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Slides'),
        'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-slides',
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => 24,
        'supports' => false,
        'can_export' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'has_archive' => false,
      ); 

    register_post_type( 'slider' , $args );
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

add_action("admin_init", "wys_slide_admin_init");
function wys_slide_admin_init(){
  add_meta_box("mb_wys_slides", "Slides", "wys_slides_display", "slider", "normal", "high");
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wys_slides_scripts' );
function wys_slides_scripts(){
    global $post_type;
    if ( $post_type == "slider" ){
        wp_enqueue_style('slider-css-styles', get_template_directory_uri().'/inc/cpt/slides.css');
    }
}

function wys_slides_display(){
    $source = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'selected_source', true );
    $image = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wys_slider_image', true );
    $video = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'video_preview', true );
    $title = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wys_slider_title', true );
    $caption = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wys_slider_caption', true );
    $link = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wys_slider_link', true );
    $target = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wys_link_target', true );
?>
<script>
function resetItAll(){
    // Clear fields
    $('#image-url').val('');
    $('#video-url').val('');
    $('#wys-slider-image').val('');
    $('#video-preview').val('');

    // Clear Uploaded Image
    $('#slide-upload').removeClass('hasimage');
    $('#slide-upload').css('background-image', 'none');

    // Clear Image by URL
    $('#slide-url').removeClass('hasimage');
    $('#slide-url').css('background-image', 'none');
    $('#slide-url .replace-image').hide();
    $('#slide-url .form-wrap').show();

    // Clear Video
    $('#slide-video').removeClass('hasimage');
    $('#slide-video').css('background-image', 'none');
    $('slide-video .replace-video').hide();
    $('#slide-video .form-wrap').show();
}
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        limiter: function(elem){
            $(this).on('keyup focus', function(){
               setCount(this, elem); 
            });
            function setCount(src, elem){
                var chars = src.value.length;
                var limit = $(src).attr('maxlength');
                if ( chars > limit ){
                    src.value = src.value.substr(0, limit);
                    chars = limit;
                }
                var charsRemaining = limit - chars;
                if ( charsRemaining <= (limit*.2) ) { var charsLeft = '<span class="charlimit-warning">'+charsRemaining+'</span>'; } else { var charsLeft = charsRemaining; }
                $(elem).html( charsLeft + '/' + limit );
            }
            setCount($(this)[0], elem);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.image-src a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var tab = $(this).data('tab');
        $('.image-src a').removeClass('selected');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('show-tab');

        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $("#slide-"+tab).addClass('show-tab');
        $('#selected-source').val(tab);
    });
    $('#upload-image').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var custom_uploader = wp.media({
        title: 'Select Slider Image',
        button: {
            text: 'Select Image'
        },
        multiple: false  // Set this to true to allow multiple files to be selected
      })
      .on('select', function() {
        var attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
        resetItAll();
        $('#slide-upload').addClass('hasimage');
        $('#slide-upload').css('background-image', 'url('+attachment.sizes.large.url+')');
        $('#wys-slider-image').val(attachment.id);
      })
      .open();
    });
    $('#fetch-image').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var imagesrc = $('#image-url').val();
        $("<img>", {
            src: imagesrc,
            error: function(){
                $('.error-msg .error-text').html('The URL you provided is not a valid image.');
                $('.error-msg').show(0, function(){
                    $('#fetch-image').click(function(){
                        $('.error-msg').fadeOut(300);
                    });
                    $('.error-msg').delay(7000).fadeOut(300);
                });
            },
            load: function(){
                resetItAll();
                $('#slide-url').addClass('hasimage');
                $('#slide-url').css('background-image', 'url('+imagesrc+')');
                $('#wys-slider-image').val(imagesrc);
                $('#slide-url .form-wrap').hide();
                $('#slide-url .replace-image').show();
            }
        });
    });
    $('#replace-image').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#image-url').val('').focus();
        $('#slide-url .replace-image').hide();
        $('#slide-url .form-wrap').show();
    });
    $('#fetch-video').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var videosrc = $('#video-url').val();
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/inc/cpt/inc.videoimg.php',
            data: { src: videosrc },
            success: function(data){
                if ( data == 'invalid.src' ) {
                    $('.error-msg .error-text').html('Please use a video from YouTube or Vimeo.');
                    $('.error-msg').show(0, function(){
                        $('#fetch-video').click(function(){
                            $('.error-msg').fadeOut(300);
                        });
                        $('.error-msg').delay(7000).fadeOut(300);
                    });
                } else {
                    resetItAll();
                    $('#slide-video').addClass('hasimage');
                    $('#slide-video').css('background-image', 'url('+data+')');
                    $('#wys-slider-image').val(videosrc);
                    $('#video-preview').val(data);
                    $('#slide-video .form-wrap').hide();
                    $('#slide-video .replace-video').show();
                }
            },
            error: function( xhr, status, error){
                if (xhr.status > 0) console.log('got error: '+status); // Status 0 - when load is interrupted
            }
        });
    });
    $('#replace-video').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#video-url').val('').focus();
        $('slide-video .replace-video').hide();
        $('#slide-video .form-wrap').show();
    });
    $('#link-target').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
            $('#wys-link-target').val('1');
        } else {
            $('#wys-link-target').val('0');
        }
    });
    $('#slide-title').limiter('#slide-title-limit');
    $('#slide-caption').limiter('#slide-caption-limit');
});
</script>
<div class="wys-slides">
  <div class="slide" id="slide">
    <div class="body">
      <div class="slide-image-wrap">
        <div class="error-msg" style="display: none;">
          <span class="dashicons dashicons-warning"></span>
          <span class="error-text">This is an error message.</span>
        </div>
        <div id="slide-upload" class="uploaded image tab-content <?php if ( $source == 'upload' && $image ) { $imgid = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image, 'large' ); echo 'hasimage show-tab" style="background-image: url('.$imgid[0].');'; } if ( !$source ) { echo 'show-tab'; } ?>">
          <a href="#upload" class="upload" id="upload-image"><span class="icon dashicons dashicons-upload"></span>
            Upload Image</a>
        </div>
        <div id="slide-url" class="from-url image tab-content <?php if ( $source == 'url' && $image ) { echo 'hasimage show-tab" style="background-image: url('.$image.');'; } ?>">
          <div class="form-wrap" <?php if ( $source == 'url' && $image ) { echo 'style="display: none;"'; } ?>>
            <label>Image URL</label>
            <input type="url" class="image-url" id="image-url" value="<?php if ( $source == 'url' && $image ) { echo $image; } ?>" />
            <input type="button" name="fetch-image" id="fetch-image" value="Get Image" />
          </div>
          <div class="replace-image hasimage" <?php if ( $source == 'url' && !$image ) { echo 'style="display: none;"'; } ?>>
            <a href="#replace-image" id="replace-image" class="upload"><span class="icon dashicons dashicons-controls-repeat"></span>
              Replace Image</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="slide-video" class="video image tab-content <?php if ( $source == 'video' && $image ) { echo 'hasimage show-tab" style="background-image: url('.$video.');'; } ?>">
          <div class="form-wrap" <?php if ( $source == 'video' && $image ) { echo 'style="display: none;"'; } ?>>
            <label>Video URL <span>Youtube or Vimeo only</span></label>
            <input type="url" class="video-url" id="video-url" value="<?php if ( $source == 'video' && $image ) { echo $video; } ?>" />
            <input type="button" name="fetch-video" id="fetch-video" value="Get Video" />
          </div>
          <div class="replace-video hasimage" <?php if ( $source == 'video' && !$image ) { echo 'style="display: none;"'; } ?>>
            <a href="#replace-video" id="replace-video" class="upload"><span class="icon dashicons dashicons-controls-repeat"></span>
              Replace Video</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="image-src">
          <a href="#upload-image" class="first <?php if ( $source == "upload" || !$source ) { echo 'selected'; } ?>" data-tab="upload"><span class="dashicons dashicons-upload"></span>
            Upload</a>
          <a href="#from-url" class="last <?php if ( $source == "url" ) { echo 'selected'; } ?>" data-tab="url"><span class="dashicons dashicons-admin-links"></span>
            From URL</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide-display-data">
        <div class="row slide-title">
          <div class="field">
            <label>
              Slide Title
              <span class="notes" id="slide-title-limit"></span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="slide-title" name="wys_slider_title" id="slide-title" maxlength="50" placeholder="Enter Title" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row slide-caption">
          <div class="field">
            <label>
              Slide Caption
              <span class="notes" id="slide-caption-limit"></span>
            </label>
            <textarea class="slide-caption" name="wys_slider_caption" maxlength="140" id="slide-caption"><?php echo $caption; ?></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row slide-link">
          <div class="field">
            <label>
              Slide Link
              <span class="notes">eg. http://www.google.com</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="slide-link" name="wys_slider_link" value="<?php echo $link; ?>" />
          </div>
          <a href="#new-tab" id="link-target" class="link-target <?php if ( $target == "1" ) { echo 'selected'; } else { } ?>" title="Open link in new tab"><span class="icon dashicons dashicons-external"></span></a>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" class="wys-link-target" id="wys-link-target" name="wys_link_target" value="<?php if ( !$target ) { echo '0'; } else { echo $target; } ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" id="selected-source" name="selected_source" value="<?php if ( !$source ) { echo 'upload'; } else { echo $source; } ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" id="wys-slider-image" name="wys_slider_image" value="<?php echo $image; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" id="video-preview" name="video_preview" value="<?php echo $video; ?>" />
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php
}

function wys_slide_title( $data , $postarr ) {
    if( $data['post_type'] == 'slider' ) {
        $slide_title = $_POST['wys_slider_title'];
        $new_title = $slide_title;
        // Set slug date
        $post_date = date('Ymd-His');
        // $post_slug = sanitize_title_with_dashes($post_date, '', $context = 'save');
        $post_slugsan = sanitize_title($post_date);
        $data['post_title'] = $new_title;
        $data['post_name'] = $post_slugsan;  
    }
    return $data;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'wys_slide_title' , '99', 2 );

add_action('save_post', 'wys_slides_save_details');

function wys_slides_save_details(){
  global $post;

  update_post_meta($post->ID, "video_preview", $_POST["video_preview"]);
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "wys_slider_image", $_POST["wys_slider_image"]);
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "selected_source", $_POST["selected_source"]);
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "wys_link_target", $_POST["wys_link_target"]);
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "wys_slider_link", $_POST["wys_slider_link"]);
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "wys_slider_caption", strip_tags($_POST["wys_slider_caption"]));
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "wys_slider_title", strip_tags($_POST["wys_slider_title"]));

}
```

Comment: How do you send `$_POST` data?

Comment: My understanding is that the function only runs when the post is submitted. The information I have provided comes from `WP_DEBUG`.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Please add the code where you define the `wys_slider_title`.

Comment: Oh, sorry. It's a text field inside of a meta box. Do you need the full code?

Comment: @Nate Yes, that would be helpful. And I would suggest using the `save_post` filter to actually save the data and make necessary changes before saving it. That's how metabox data is usually saved.

Comment: As you have guessed the `$_POST['wys_slider_title'];` is null, meaning that the variable is not declared. No matter the problem you should always do a check if the variable `isset()` or if you want to handle empty titles etc if is `empty()`.

Comment: And as kabiir said better to use `save_post`

Comment: Ok. I'll post the full thing in a second. However, @Kabiir, I have `save_post` running as an action for the other fields, but it is that one field when it accepts a new post title that is causing some problems.  But the metabox data (content, link, etc.) is all saves using the `save_post` action.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following improvements for better code readability and to make it easier to maintain later.

1. Assuming you've removed **title** from your custom post type using the following function :

   ```
   remove_post_type_support( 'slider', 'title' )
   ```

   Now if you use `name="post_title"` instead of `name="wys_slider_title"`
   WordPress will still use it and update the post title accordingly. Hence you don't have to worry about the title and you can focus on your custom fields. This results in a much better code and solves your problem of duplicating the title and then saving it. 
   *This helps you avoid using `wp_insert_post_data` additional filter. 
   *And since you're not manually updating the title using `wp_update_post` function, you don't have to worry about the `save_post` infinite loop.
2. Before you save any data, you want to make sure there's nothing malicious in there. Fortunately, WordPress provides a bunch of functions for [Data Validation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation)

   ```
   // Use:
   update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_meta_box_text', wp_kses( $_POST['my_meta_box_text'], $allowed ) );
   // Instead of:
   update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_meta_box_text', $_POST['my_meta_box_text'] );
   ```
3. Use `save_post_{$post_type}` instead of plain `save_post`, This helps you avoid unnecesary `IF` statements 
   e.g. In your case,
   `add_action( 'save_post_slider', 'wys_slides_save_details' );`

   you won't need to wrap your logic around an `IF` statement

   ```
   if( $post_type == 'slider' ) {...CODE...}
   ```

   Since `save_post_slider` will only run for `Slider` post type.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the `wys_slide_title` filter and move the logic inside `save_post` action. Haven't test it but is should work.

```
add_action('save_post', 'wys_slides_save_details');

function wys_slides_save_details($post_id){

  $post = get_post($post_id);

  if( $post->post_type == 'slider' ) {

    update_post_meta($post->ID, "video_preview", $_POST["video_preview"]);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "wys_slider_image", $_POST["wys_slider_image"]);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "selected_source", $_POST["selected_source"]);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "wys_link_target", $_POST["wys_link_target"]);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "wys_slider_link", $_POST["wys_slider_link"]);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "wys_slider_caption", strip_tags($_POST["wys_slider_caption"]));
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "wys_slider_title", strip_tags($_POST["wys_slider_title"]));

    $slide_title = sanitize_text_field($_POST['wys_slider_title']);
    $new_title = $slide_title;
    // Set slug date
    $post_date = date('Ymd-His');
    // $post_slug = sanitize_title_with_dashes($post_date, '', $context = 'save');
    $post_slugsan = sanitize_title($post_date);  

    /* To avoid infinite loops */

    remove_action( 'save_post', 'wys_slides_save_details' );

    wp_update_post( array( 'post_title' => $new_title, 'post_name' => $post_slugsan ) );

    add_action( 'save_post', 'wys_slides_save_details' );

  }

}
```

Comment: From your function, what's `$data`? It doesn't look to be declared anywhere. The `$data['post_type']` conditional checks the post type, and whilst that comes from the `wys_slide_title` filter, `$data` is declared there, so it can verify the post type. I'm sure somewhere I've got the way to check, but I just wanted to flag that up for you.

Comment: It should be `$post->post_type`. Also, you sanitized the title, which apparently makes it into a post slug (at least from the admin area). I've removed it. However, locally the function works.

Comment: Oh my bad. Sorry I forgot to replace the `$data['post_type']` with `$post->post_type` as you mentioned. I put `sanitize_title` as a reference that you should sanitize/escape every user input. I change it to `sanitize_text_field` which I am guessing is what you need.

Answer (score -1):

You should use save_post_{post_type} instead  of save_post . Hooking to this action you wouldn't have to check on the post type (ie: if ( $slug != $_POST['post_type'] )).

Read below mentioned article for same...

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post